# how to use multiple edittext on single image

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

I have 16 edittext's in single row for that I am using single background image.
My problem is

1.focus comes only when I touch on start of edittext but I want that when I click anywhere on edittext.
2.when set width of edittext it looks good on AVD but when I test on real device it reduces. How to handle this.

I am a newbie, so thanks for the help

i have tried this so far :

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="@drawable/table_back" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/req"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/fm"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/effects"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sev"
    android:layout_width="33dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/causes"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/occ"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/process"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/det"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rpn"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/recommended"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sev2"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/occ2"
    android:layout_width="37dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/det2"
    android:layout_width="38dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/new_rpn"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/resp"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/target_date"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:editable="false"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />


</TableRow>
```

Comment: each box should be editText?

Comment: but how can i define this..there is a single image

Comment: question not clear, what you want? And what are you getting?

Comment: when i test my code in emulater it works perfectlly.but in real device size of edittext shrink.i give 80 width for first edittext after text so second edittext start from second box showing in image.but in real device it start before the second box.

Answer (score 0):

Open image wiht microsoft office picture manager->Edit_pictures->Crop

- set your box u get new Height width in pixcels.
- convert pixcel to dp by http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/
- set this width to edit text.

Hope this will help you.